Gtk4 Gridview Example needed
I'm redeveloping an application written previously with PyQt6 and Python now using PyGObject (Gtk4) and Python.
I'm looking for a complete example showing how to use a GridView which appears to have replaced the Table Widget within Gtk4.  The only example I was able to find was very basic and did not show how to configure the columns with headers nor setting up the model which the widget needs to display cursor data from a mysql database.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated !
